# Grep - remove characters from lines of a file

Tags: grep

I have a file containing the following lines:

```
56228//Ube2j1
68192//Leprotl1
66074//Tmem167
66074//Tmem167
66074//Tmem167
56445//Dnaja2
72061//2010111I01Rik
```

What is the best command to return the following? Basically I only want to return characters after the `//`.

```
Ube2j1
Leprotl1
Tmem167
Tmem167
Tmem167
Dnaja2
2010111I01Rik
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lookbehinds in grep (*which includes `-P` parameter*)  to print all the characters which are just after to `//`,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\/\/).*' file
Ube2j1
Leprotl1
Tmem167
Tmem167
Tmem167
Dnaja2
2010111I01Rik
```

You could also use `\K` in the regex to discard the previously matched characters.

```
$ grep -oP '\/\/\K.*' file
Ube2j1
Leprotl1
Tmem167
Tmem167
Tmem167
Dnaja2
2010111I01Rik
```

Use the below sed command, only if you want to print the blank lines in between.

```
$ sed 's/^.*\/\///g' file
Ube2j1

Leprotl1

Tmem167

Tmem167

Tmem167

Dnaja2

2010111I01Rik
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `cut`:

```
cut -f3 -d/ filename
```

Output:

```
Ube2j1

Leprotl1

Tmem167

Tmem167

Tmem167

Dnaja2

2010111I01Rik
```

Answer (score 0):

The following grep command will extract any text following the two slashes. One note is that it will only extract the part of the string from the end, not from the beginning (e.g., with "123//456//789", it would return "789", instead of "456//789).

```
$ grep -o "[^\/][^\/.]*$" file
Ube2j1
Leprotl1
Tmem167
Tmem167
Tmem167
Dnaja2
2010111I01Rik
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` will do the job:

```
awk -F"//" '{print $2}' file
Ube2j1
Leprotl1
Tmem167
Tmem167
Tmem167
Dnaja2
2010111I01Rik
```